# minipage, bullet, left margin, align with top line

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, bullets

I am using minipage.
and make bullet in the minipage.
and the text next to the bullet is long and it becomes several lines

however, the second line does not aligned with the first line that next to the bullet

this is my code. I need help

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}
  {\bf Text not that long} \\
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.29\textwidth}
  \hfill {\bf MM. YY-}\\ \hspace*{0.83in}{\bf MM. YY}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\textwidth}
$\bullet$ \it Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, \\
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what the result should look like, but if I understand the bit with the alignment you should use the `itemize` environment instead of putting the `\bullet` by hand.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Unrelated, but note `\bf` has been deprecated for,  25 years or so. Use `\bfseries` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This does exactly the same as your code above but using a `tabular` instead of `minipage`s.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{.7\linewidth} @{} >{\raggedleft\bfseries\arraybackslash}p{.3\linewidth}@{}}
\textbf{Text not that long} & MM. YY-\par MM. YY \\
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=*]
  \item \textit{Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long,}
  \item \textit{Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long, Text very long,}
\end{itemize} & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]